# Checking if a string is a permutation of another string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have been practicing programming questions and came across this one

> Given string A and B, check if string B is a permutation of string A

I wrote my answer and compared it to the books answer but mine was completely different. I then researched on StackOverflow and haven't seen anyone answer this question with my solution.

There are two solutions I've seen

1. Sort both strings and then compare them. This takes O(nlogn) time and depending on the sorting algorithm it would take up O(n), O(logn) or O(1) memory.
2. Create a hash-map and have the keys be the characters of the strings and the values be ints initialized to 0. When you see a character in string A increment the value by 1. When you see a character in string B decrement it by 1. In the end all values should be 0 if it is a permutation. This takes O(n) time and O(n) memory.

My solution was to hash the strings and then compare the hash values, if they are equal then the strings must be a permutation.

**My Solution In C++**

```
bool isPerm(string a, string b) {
    if(a.length() != b.length()) return false;
    return hashString(a) == hashString(b);
}

long hashString(string a) {
    long hashed = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) { 
        hashed += a[i] * 7; // Timed by a prime to make the hash more unique?
    } 
    return hashed;
}
```

This solution runs in O(n) time and in O(1) memory.

**Questions**

1. Is this a valid answer?
2. If the hash ins't unique enough, is there a way to make it unique?

**EDIT**

As everyone has pointed out my solution can not be used. As `ad` will hash to `bc` and those are not permutations.

Comment: Check `isPerm("ad", "bc")`.

Comment: Question for you: given two arrays of size n, if the sum of the arrays is equal can you be sure that they have the same elements ? This is kind of what you are assuming in your hash comparison. Btw that `*7` does no good

Comment: [std::is_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation)

Comment: Do note that generally two string containing the same letters in a different order should produce different hashes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fdd4c37c1af0c0b

Comment: Your implementation fails in simplest example like `isPerm("ab", "ba")` return false.

Comment: This question has a duplicate in the Java world? Since when can you freely use Java in C++?

Comment: I guess since someone once asked this question then no one can ever ask it again with a different context? That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to compare unique character counts for each string:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool checkPermutation(string a, string b) {
  unordered_map<char, int> aCounts;
  for (auto c : a) {
    aCounts[c]++;
  }

  unordered_map<char, int> bCounts;
  for (auto c : b) {
    bCounts[c]++;
  }

  if (aCounts.size() != bCounts.size()) {
    return false;
  }

  for (auto p : aCounts) {
    char c = p.first;
    if (bCounts.count(c)) {
      if (aCounts.at(c) != bCounts.at(c)) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. your proposed hash is not valid because multiple strings can hash to the same value, that are not necessarily a permutation of each other (e.g. "14" and "23"); you are effectively just multiplying your string's ascii values by `7`, so *your hashing is checking if the strings sum up to the same value*, not if they are a permutation of each other
2. To make the hash unique, you can represent your string as a number in the base of your alphabet; i.e. `hash = sum(c[i] * alpha ^ (i - 1))`, where `c` is your string, and `alpha` is the number of letters in the alphabet; however since the hashes are now unique, `hash(a) == hash(b)` implies `a == b` which is not what you want; (this also has other problems of its own, such as overflows, quite complex computation)

I would stick with Option 1: with fixed alphabet size `a`, you can use an `O(n)` time `O(a)` space counting sort for example, which is *clearly an optimal solution for this problem* (constant space, bounded by input time).

Option 2 also seems wrong to me, but maybe I just don't understand it: what if the input is `aa` and `bb`, flip `a` and `b` twice, everything is false, they don't look like permutations to me. You could of course keep a character occurrence map for each string which would require `O(a)` memory and `O(n)` time for an alphabet of size `a`, which is basically the same thing as a counting sort :)

Comment: You're right about number 2 I was mistaken. You are suppose to use an int as a value and increment the value on every letter you see. Then on the other string decrement the value for ever letter you see. The values should be 0 in the end.